# При парсенге записает GUI

Tags: c#, gui, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте Уважаемые!
В C# новичек, поэтому вопрос возможно слишком простой.

Опишу суть программы:

1. Программа постоянно парсит определенные данные с сайта, при этом ходит по всем страницам.
2. При этом, записывает найденные данные в `ListBox`.
3. При парсенге, весь GUI интерфейс зависает до полного окончания парсинга.

Мне нужно что бы при парсинге можно было работать с полученными данными и получать новые.
Покажите пожалуйста код с примерной реализацией.

Спасибо!

Comment: Отделите интерфейс от логики и выполняйте их в разных потоках.

Comment: Я это понимаю. Что нужны потоки.  
Я с потоками  никогда не работал, и не знаю как отделить саму форму от парсинга

Comment: Вас забанили во всех поисковиках?

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте про MVVM, это модный и лучший на сегодня паттерн отделения UI от логики.

Вкратце:

- создайте набор классов (модель), который будут заниматься обходом страниц и разбором содержимого этих страниц
- запустите их в рабочем потоке, дайте возможность внешнему коду добавлять задания.
- пусть модель выставляет события, которые сигнализируют о приходе новой информации
- создайте классы, подписывающиеся на события модели, перебрасывающие данные в UI-поток, и записывающие их в dependency property или observable collection (view model)
- создайте UI, который будет привязан (через Binding) к данных из view model

Voilà, всё крутится в разных потоках и ничего не виснет.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно запускать операцию в отдельном потоке. Самое простое решение это использовать BackgroundWorker. Можете почитать от нём вот здесь.

[BackgroundWorker - класс](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

По мне для новичка самое оно.